# Openpyxl - turn off Bandedcolumns - table formatting

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, openpyxl, conditional-formatting

I have a data in master excel file which I am trying to split and store it in multiple child excel files.

I would like to format the data in child files as a table.

So, I tried the below code

```
tab = Table(displayName = "Table1", ref = "A1:" + get_column_letter(wb1.worksheets[0].max_column) + str(wb1.worksheets[0].max_row) )
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium2", showFirstColumn=True, showLastColumn=True, showRowStripes=True, showColumnStripes=True)
tab.tableStyleInfo = style
wb1.worksheets[0].add_table(tab)
```

But in my master file, the `TableStyleMedium2` looks like below

[image]

When I apply the same style to my child file (shown in code above), it looks slightly different

[image]

You can see that alternate rows are not fully white. instead only certain cells are white.

I found out that openpyxl takes `Bandedcolumns=True` by default but I am unable to turn it off programmatically. I am able to manually resolve this issue by unchecking `Bandedcolumns` but how do I do it using openpyxl

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'showBandedColumns'

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Why is this question being marked to close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes

```
showRowStripes=
showColumnStripes=
```

control the Style options ***'Banded Rows'*** and ***'Banded Columns'*** in the Table design Tab respectively, setting to False will disable

```
style = TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium2", 
                       showFirstColumn=True,
                       showLastColumn=True, 
                       showRowStripes=True, 
                       showColumnStripes=False)
```

will uncheck the ***'Banded Columns'*** box.

Comment: Is this something that you would be able to help me with?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658422/openpyxl-write-text-in-between-and-at-the-end-of-a-cell