# Xlwings write text in-between and at the end of a cell

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, xlwings

I have a data like as below.

[image]

```
ABC 1   300 500 "He is a good student and has scored lot of marks in 2nd term during
                 He also focuses on extracurricular activities"
DEF 2   400 600 "He is a good student and has scored lot of marks in 2nd term during
                 He also focuses on extracurricular activities"
```

I would like to two keywords/sentence to each student based on a criteria like below

ABC - "2nd term during Aug, 2022", "Needs Improvement on Maths"

DEF - "2nd term during Aug, 2022","Needs Improvement on Science"

So, I tried the below

```
wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb["input"]
for i in range(A1:A1048756):
    s = ws.cell(i).value
    if s == 'ABC': 
        ws.cell(i).value = s.replace(
            "He is a good student and has scored lot of marks in 2nd term during",
            "He is a good student and has scored lot of marks in 2nd term during Aug,2022. Needs improvement on Maths")
```

However, am not sure whether this is the best way to do this. Moreover, I don't know how can I set formatting for certain part of the text in a cell.

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Comment: You cannot manipulate text inside a cell with Openpyxl. You could extract the text in a cell  to a string, reformat with the extra text you want to include and then write that string back to the cell. However you cannot have changes to the font like some part highlighted (bold) in Red. You **can** do this with Xlwings however, the character attribute allows you to manipulate text within the cell. Look at this as an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73526687/how-to-put-style-in-the-middle-of-a-string/73527001#73527001

Comment: @moken - useful to know. I referred your linked post. I guess we can also change the style of text (part) that we would like to using xlwings. Am I righ? Along with font size and color

Comment: Font name of the individual characters? yes and insert the text were you want it rather than extracting the cell value, changing then writing back to cell. I will post an example of this in a short while

Comment: @moken - that would be really helpful. You can show in xlwings on how we can insert text like shown in my post. I updated the tags to xlwings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example code concentrating on the first student only.
I'm assuming the comments section uses a template since the initial text for both students is the same. Therefore just working on adding the unique highlighted text. Either way obviously the other text can also be written at the same time if necessary.
Depending on how common the text is you can hard set your indexes or calculate from the length of the text. The date text position is calculated, the improvement text position is counted.

```
import xlwings as xw

filename = "foo.xlsx"
date_text = 'Aug 2022'
improve_text = 'Needs improvement on'
line1_date_pos = 67  # Length of the text that precedes the date entry

with xw.App() as app:
    wb = app.books.open(filename)
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    date_offset = line1_date_pos + len(date_text)+1
    # Insert the date text into the cell, need to use '.api.Text' and just use
    # the index of the position where the text is to be inserted
    ws['E2'].characters[line1_date_pos].api.Text = " " + date_text + "\n"
    # Setting date text formatting requires start and end index, the end index is
    # calculated from the date text length added to the start index +1
    ws['E2'].characters[line1_date_pos:date_offset].font.bold = True
    ws['E2'].characters[line1_date_pos:date_offset].font.color = (255, 0, 0)

    # If the text template is common, the indexes might be able to be hard set.
    # Be aware text inserted by the code could change index positions 
    ws['E2'].characters[123].api.Text = "\n" + improve_text + " Maths"
    ws['E2'].characters[144:149].font.name = 'Calibri'
    ws['E2'].characters[144:149].font.size = '14'
    ws['E2'].characters[144:149].font.italic = True
    ws['E2'].characters[123:149].font.bold = True
    ws['E2'].characters[123:149].font.color = (255, 0, 0)

    wb.save(filename)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: I have a related question on formatting a specific text. Would you be interested to look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852099/xlwings-find-text-start-and-end-position-and-color-it