# xlwings find specific char text start and end position and format it

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, formatting, xlwings

I have multiple excel files with 12 sheets in each file.

[image]

So, in each sheet, I have a fixed text like below - "Project has been blocked"

So, I would like to do the below

a) Find the text "Project has been blocked" wherever it appears and change it is formatting like below (with bold red color) as shown below

b) save the excel file as .xlsx

I tried the below

```
req_text = "Project has been blocked"

for a_cell in ws.used_range:
        if a_cell.value == req_text:
            print(a_cell.address)
            col = a_cell.address[0]
            ws[col].characters.font.bold = True  #how to get the start and end position of my text
            ws[col].characters.font.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

But this doesn't work correctly. As I am unable to get the start and end position of my text.

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

**update**

```
files = glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'\\sheet_replaced_files\\'+'YR2022_*.xlsx')
for old_filename in files:
    old_filename = old_filename.split('sheet_replaced_files\\')[1]
    print(old_filename)
    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
        app.display_alerts = False
        
        def find_next_cell(start_cell):
            found_cell = ws.api.UsedRange.Find(req_text,
                                       After=start_cell,
                                       LookIn=xlValues,
                                       SearchOrder=xlByColumns,
                                       SearchDirection=xlNext,
                                       MatchCase=False)
            return found_cell
        
        workbook = xw.Book(os.getcwd()+'\\sheet_replaced_files\\'+old_filename)
        ws = workbook.sheets('5) Development')
        # First cell to start searching for req_text
        search_from_cell = ws.api.Range('A1')
        count = 0
        first_search_cell = ''
        


        while True:
            # Search for next cell to update
            update_cell = find_next_cell(search_from_cell)
            print(update_cell) #returns None here
            # Excel search will restart search again from the beginning after the last match
            # is found exit the loop when find the first match again
            if update_cell._inner.Address != first_search_cell:
                print(update_cell._inner.Address)
                # Set the address of the first found cell
                if count == 0:
                    first_search_cell = update_cell._inner.Address
                cell_column = update_cell._inner.Column
                cell_row = update_cell._inner.Row

                text = ws.range(cell_row, cell_column).value
                len_req_text = len(req_text)

                # Create a List of the start position for all instances of the req_text
                # tsi = text position index
                tsi_list = [index for index in range(len(text)) if text.startswith(req_text, index)]

                # Iterate the tsi list
                for i in range(len(tsi_list)):
                    # Get the index of the text position, tps = text position start
                    tps = tsi_list[i]
                    # Use the tps as start of the character position of the req_text
                    # and (tps + length of req_text) for the end character position
                    ws.range(cell_row, cell_column).characters[tps:tps + len_req_text].font.bold = False
                    ws.range(cell_row, cell_column).characters[tps:tps + len_req_text].font.color = (0,255,0)

                search_from_cell = ws.api.Range(update_cell._inner.Address.replace('$', ''))

                count += 1

            else:
                break

        workbook.save(os.getcwd()+'\\colored_text\\'+old_filename)
```

Sometimes, I also get an error message like below

---

```
----
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

<timed exec> in find_next_cell(start_cell)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    103         while True:
    104             try:
--> 105                 v = self.__method(*args, **kwargs)
    106                 if isinstance(v, (CDispatch, CoClassBaseClass, DispatchBaseClass)):
    107                     return COMRetryObjectWrapper(v)

C:\Users\Aksh~1\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.9\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9.py in Find(self, What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)
  33513     def Find(self, What=defaultNamedNotOptArg, After=defaultNamedNotOptArg, LookIn=defaultNamedNotOptArg, LookAt=defaultNamedNotOptArg
  33514             , SearchOrder=defaultNamedNotOptArg, SearchDirection=1, MatchCase=defaultNamedOptArg, MatchByte=defaultNamedOptArg, SearchFormat=defaultNamedOptArg):
> 33515         ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(398, LCID, 1, (9, 0), ((12, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (3, 49), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),What
  33516                         , After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection
  33517             , MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352571), 9)
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: The 6 instances of the text "Project has been blocked" is all in the one cell, right?

Comment: yes, correct (in this example). In one cell, we have multiple copies of same keyword. But in real time, they can be repeated the same way for another user (another row) as well. So, wherever it appears, we should change the formatting

Comment: But yes, each row (user) will have multiple instances of the text in one cell only.

Comment: Also updated another error message that I got when executing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the code to include an Excel search for the text in the used data of the sheet, and then update that cell text with Bold-Red as desired per the original code.
I ended up having to use a while loop for the Excel search and break out when the search looped back to the first found cell. Therefore the code keeps track of the **first_search_cell** to compare with the next found cell in the while loop.
I've left the Excel search variables as constants so you know what the name and value is if you want to change the search options. Obviously you can delete the ones you don't want or use import from Xlwings constants.
Otherwise its pretty much the same.

```
...
# Excel Search constants
# class LookAt:
xlPart = 2  # from enum XlLookAt
xlWhole = 1  # from enum XlLookAt
# class FindLookIn:
xlComments = -4144  # from enum XlFindLookIn
xlFormulas = -4123  # from enum XlFindLookIn
xlValues = -4163  # from enum XlFindLookIn
# class SearchOrder:
xlByColumns = 2  # from enum XlSearchOrder
xlByRows = 1  # from enum XlSearchOrder
# class SearchDirection:
xlNext = 1  # from enum XlSearchDirection
xlPrevious = 2  # from enum XlSearchDirection


def find_next_cell(start_cell):
    # Import xlwings constants for search parameters
    from xlwings import constants
    found_cell = ws.api.UsedRange.Find(req_text,
                                       After=start_cell,
                                       LookIn=constants.FindLookIn.xlValues,
                                       SearchOrder=constants.SearchOrder.xlByColumns,
                                       SearchDirection=constants.SearchDirection.xlNext,
                                       MatchCase=False)
    return found_cell


wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

req_text = "Project has been blocked"

# First cell to start searching for req_text
search_from_cell = ws.api.Range('A1')

count = 0
first_search_cell = ''
while True:
    # Search for next cell to update
    update_cell = find_next_cell(search_from_cell)

    # Excel search will restart search again from the beginning after the last match
    # is found exit the loop when find the first match again
    if update_cell._inner.Address != first_search_cell:
        print(update_cell._inner.Address)
        # Set the address of the first found cell
        if count == 0:
            first_search_cell = update_cell._inner.Address

        cell_column = update_cell._inner.Column
        cell_row = update_cell._inner.Row

        text = ws.range(cell_row, cell_column).value
        len_req_text = len(req_text)

        # Create a List of the start position for all instances of the req_text
        # tsi = text position index
        tsi_list = [index for index in range(len(text)) if text.startswith(req_text, index)]

        # Iterate the tsi list
        for i in range(len(tsi_list)):
            # Get the index of the text position, tps = text position start
            tps = tsi_list[i]
            # Use the tps as start of the character position of the req_text
            # and (tps + length of req_text) for the end character position
            ws.range(cell_row, cell_column).characters[tps:tps + len_req_text].font.bold = True
            ws.range(cell_row, cell_column).characters[tps:tps + len_req_text].font.color = (255, 0, 0)

        search_from_cell = ws.api.Range(update_cell._inner.Address.replace('$', ''))

        count += 1

    else:
        break

wb.save('foo.xlsx')
...
```

Comment: how do we get the `X` and `Y` value? Because they occur more than 40-50 times in each sheet. So, how do we get their X and Y?

Comment: Meaning, there is no pattern/rule that I can know where they appear. They might appear in any rows and columns.

Comment: I guess I should change `text.startswith` to `text.contains`? because as shown in example, they might appear after a random keywords/texts. So, do you think `contains` would be appropriate? or by using `startswith`, we are only looking for specific char position in our data

Comment: Really appreciate your help. If we don't have `contains` attribute, do you think we will be able to identify the `req_text` correctly? because they always appear only after certain keywords/texts (the cell text don't start with "project has been blocked"). So, cell text usually contains the `req_text` but don't start with `req_text`

Comment: **startswith** is just saying does the text from this postion match the 'req_text' text. We are specifying the *start* to vary the point of where we take the start of text to be. So it's like chopping the text string up at the points the 'req_text' exists. I may be missing something but I think it would be fine so long as the 'req_text' can be unique enough to detect only those positions you want. If there are any issues with this method then we can certainly look at alternates.

Comment: Let's say if I manually find out that the `req_text` appears only in `Column I`, `Column AC` etc. Is it possible to hardcode this in code anywhere instead of doing full excel sheet search. We can reduce time taken (because it will look at only those columns). I should just change like below - `ws.api.Range(AC:AC)` - So, this will look at all rows in Column AC?

Comment: Yep, if you had specified that the cells to update were only in a certain column I'd have just used a cell iteration through that column(s) instead.

Comment: I benefit through your code already. I was just curious to know if there is a req in future that req_text will be present in certain columns, it doesn't make sense to search full excel sheet. So, I asked you. I guess just replacing `used_range` with `range(AC:AC)` should be fine to find for text in a specific column. Right? And the error is gone now for some reason. I closed and reopened excel and it is gone

Comment: Yes, changing **ws.api.UsedRange.Find** to **ws.api.Range('AC:AC').Find** (case sensitive attributes and included quotes in the range) should just search the column AC.

Comment: I pasted my code in the post. For some reason, when I use your code within a context manager, I get `None` for print(update_cell). Not sure what is the issue. If possible, can help me know whether am making any issue with the alignment or something else?

Comment: I checked you code looks OK. Then copied to run it locally. Obviously needed to make a couple of changes to the input workbook and sheet but otherwise pretty much running your code as is. Had no issues with the search finding, printing the cells to change then saving the workbook. I noticed when opening the completed book you changed the colour to green.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248374/discussion-between-moken-and-the-great).

Comment: I found out something. I pasted a screenshot above. If I key in `ws.api.Range('A1')`, it throws com error. whereas if I type in `ws.api.Range('B1')`, your code works (without context manager). whereas if I put with clause and type  `ws.api.Range('B1')`, I get the below error - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inner'`. So, `A1` always throws COM error (irrespective of with clause or not). Is it because of how my sheet looks like (shown above)?